# whats wrong with this ajax function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my ajax function and

```
$('#save_form_3').button({
    icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-disk"
    }
})
.click(function (event) {
    if($('#guarantor_details').validate().form()){
    var form_3_data = $("#guarantor_details").serialize();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: form_3_data,
            success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert(response);
                if(response=="success"){
                    alert(response);
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
    });     
    return false;       
    }
});
```

first alert gives me message "success" and second alert doesn't execute. seems like if condition not working under success function.

any idea why it doesn't?

im using jquery-1.6.2.min.js.

maybe problem in jquery 1.6.2 or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks

```
if($SQL_INSERT){
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo mysql_error(); 
}
```

thats insert.php anyway

`if($.trim(response)=="success")` works

Comment: Try `if($.trim(response)=="success")` just for kicks, my hunch is you have an extra space on there on one side of "success".

Comment: trim the response and then compare it.. response might have contain spaces

Comment: anyway you should use `console.log` instead of `alert` for debuging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing any whitespaces/newlines outside the  tags in your insert.php file.

Comment: if($SQL_INSERT){
  echo "success";
 }else{
  echo mysql_error(); 
 } thats insert.php anyway if($.trim(response)=="success") works

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a simple regex?

Instead of `response=="success"`, try `/success/.test(response)`

This will return true if success is anywhere in the response string.